# Change data within a struct across views in swiftUi

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

i wanted to share data across multiple views, but the changes only affect locally, I want it globally, is there a way in swift or to be specific SwiftUI to change data globally??
(note: without binding)

my main View

```
struct UIController: View {
    @ObservedObject var userAuth = AuthUser() // I want to affect this value, isLogin
    @State var showLogin:Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            homeLogin()
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $userAuth.isLogin, content: AfterLogin.init)
            Text("\(String(self.userAuth.isLogin))")
        }
    }
}
```

The View that change the value :

```
struct LoginForm: View {
    @StateObject var userAuth = AuthUser()
    @State var username:String = ""
    @State var passwd:String = ""
    @State var isShowPasswd:Bool = false
    var body: some View {
Button(action: {
                    self.userAuth.isLogin = true
                }) {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth-100, height: 50, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .foregroundColor(.purple)
                        .overlay(
                            Text("Log In")
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(Font.system(size: 20, design: .rounded)))
                }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable the sharing/setting of data that will cause your SwiftUI views to update, you can implement the following strategy:

1. Either a) use a separate class to hold the data using `ObservableObject`, or b) make your `AuthUser` conform to the `ObservableObject` protocol. Use the `@Published` property wrapper on the data you want available to your SwiftUI views:

```
class AuthUser: ObservableObject {
    @Published var someProperty: Bool = false
}
```

2. In your `SceneDelegate`, set the `.environmentObject` view modifier on your `ContentView`, passing in a reference to `AuthUser`:

```
    static let authUser = AuthUser()
    

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        let contentView = ContentView()

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(SceneDelegate.authUser))
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

3. In your SwiftUI views, make the data available using the `@EnvironmentObject` property wrapper:

```
struct LoginForm: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var swiftUIauth: AuthUser

    var body: some View {
       ...
```

4. Use `swiftUIauth.someProperty` however you'd like. If the value changes, your SwiftUI views will update.